# How to save multiple persons names with their corresponding emails in shared preference?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am a newbie for android development. I want to save the multiple person's and their corresponding email-id's.I am done with saving single person but got stuck at saving the data for multiple persons as there is a list of persons. Following is my code for saving the details for a single person.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
TextView name;
TextView email;
public static final String mypreference = "mypref";
public static final String Name = "nameKey";
public static final String Email = "emailKey";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedpreferences.contains(Name)) {
        name.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Name, ""));
    }
    if (sharedpreferences.contains(Email)) {
        email.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Email, ""));

    }

}
 public void Save(View view) {
    String n = name.getText().toString();
    String e = email.getText().toString();
    Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(Name, n);
    editor.putString(Email, e);
    editor.commit();
}

public void clear(View view) {
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    name.setText("");
    email.setText("");

}

public void Get(View view) {
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (sharedpreferences.contains(Name)) {
        name.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Name, ""));
    }
    if (sharedpreferences.contains(Email)) {
        email.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Email, ""));

    }
}
```

Please help/guide me to achieve the task.

Comment: better to store your values in database

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are doing it in a wrong way.Please use sqlite database instead of sharedprefrence to insert multiple records like name and email.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo

It might help you.

You are able to store lists in sharedPreferences with help of this class

```
ArrayList<Person> usersWhoWon = new ArrayList<Person>();
tinydb.putListObject("allWinners" usersWhoWon);
```